# ValueError: None values not supported. - Keras Custom Loss Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

Im getting this error on my custom loss function : ValueError: None values not supported.

The output is a 2d array of binary digits (2000,2).
I need to calculate the accuracy on certain entries only (selected by the NN), not the entire set.

Here's my loss function and how i did it:

```
def getBalance(x_true, x_pred):

    ##Selected entries for calculation
    x_pred = K.tf.round(x_pred)
    trade_index = K.tf.not_equal(x_pred[:,1], 0 )

    x_true_tradeable  = K.tf.boolean_mask(x_true[:,0], trade_index)
    x_pred_tradeable  = K.tf.boolean_mask(x_pred[:,0], trade_index)


    Accuracy = K.mean(K.equal(x_true_tradeable, x_pred_tradeable))
    return Accuracy
```

Here is my model for reference:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.4, input_shape=(train_input_data_NN.shape[1], train_input_data_NN.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(30, dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.4,  return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='getBalance', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(train_input_data_NN, outputs_NN, epochs=50,  batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_data=(test_input_data_NN, outputs_NN_test))
```

Comment: Your loss is not differentiable. Don't use `K.tf.round` and `K.equal`.

Comment: so what should i replace it with?